# Access denied due to invalid subscription key (Face API)

Tags: face-detection, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am having trouble using Microsoft Face API. Below is my sample request:

```
curl -v -X POST "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 1xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxd" --data-ascii "{\"url\":\"http://www.mrbeantvseries.co.uk/bean3.jpg\"}"
```

I use the subscription id from my cognitive services account and I got below response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unspecified",
    "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."
  }
}
```

Not sure if I've missed out anything there. Can someone help me on this? Very much appreciated.

Comment: URL: https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/

Comment: You might want to check this to make sure that you're passing the right key - [Where to find my Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key in Windows azure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40867834/465053)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you've entered your Azure subscription ID instead?
In the Azure portal, you can find the API key under 'Keys', shown below:

[image: Azure Portal screenshot]

It will be a 32-digit hexadecimal number, no hyphens.

Comment: Hi @cthrash, you are right. Previously I've also tried both of those keys but it returned error. Now that I tried again and it's working. Must be some mistake before. Thanks for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same problem. I read the API documentation and it states the following.

You must use the same region in your REST API call as you used to obtain your subscription keys.

**First, you must find the location of your subscription.**
In order to find the location of your subscription region, you must go to **Cognitive Services -> Properties** under the Label **Location**, you will find your subscription region.
See below. [image]

**Second you must find the correct endpoint to make the call to.**
For example, if I want to make a call to the Computer Vision API, 
My location is East US, I will use either key 1 or 2, then I will use the following endpoint
East US - https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect

You will now be able to have access to the API.

Comment: great bro u saved my life :D thnks

Comment: THANK YOU this was the worst bug

Answer (score 7):

I had faced the same issue, it seems like there is some problem with the keys generated newly. To fix this you can actually add your endpoint as well, when you create the object for `IFaceServiceClient`. You can see the code below.

```
private readonly IFaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient("your key", "Your endpoint");
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - I had to add the endpoint. IFaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient(ai.key1, "https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0")

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. I figure it might be helpful to some people, so I am posting it here. (btw Azure support points me to this post here)

I was trying to run through the sample file for ImageSearch of Azure. I was refering to these pages:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/quickstarts/csharp
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/quickstarts/client-libraries?tabs=visualstudio&pivots=programming-language-csharp
- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/blob/master/BingSearchv7/BingImageSearch/quickstart/bing-image-search-quickstart-csharp.cs

I was receiving a mixture of *404 Not Found error & 401 unauthorized error* when send requests to the Bing Search resource, using
Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Search.ImageSearch. I figure it must be something wrong with either my credentials or my endpoints.

After struggling with it for hours, reading through posts and talking to Azure support member, I finally find the problems:

1. The base Uri Endpoint I was assigned on the *Azure Keys & Endpoints webpage* is **incomplete**. (https://api.bing.microsoft.com/)
2. The base Uri Endpoint on the *sample tutorial pages* was **outdated** because of the 2020.10.30 transition between *Cognitive Services to Bing Search Services*. (https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search)

**As of 2021.09.22, the correct global base Uri Endpoint for Bing Image Search is:**
**https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/images/search**

Hope this would be helpful to anyone and save mankind some time.

Answer (score 1):

CesarB is correct. You must create a Resource of Cognitive Service in Azure first and then get the subscription key from it. 
the region is not always 'westus', it really depends on what region you select when you created the resource. You can also check it on the endpoint of overview of the Resource

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint
https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0

**Endpoint and the subscription key must be consistent.**

look at Microsoft *Overview* for this info!

Answer (score 0):

I was using a wrong header in my Http call and had the same error message

I changed "api-key" header

[image]

To be replace by "Opc-Apim-Subscription-Key"

[image: ![enter image description here]