# 401 access denied with cognitive-services keys (not azure account)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I would like to test cognitive-services "face detect"

- I created an account in :
  https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-US/subscriptions
  with
  Face-Free soubscription : 
  ok I have 2 keys

(not azure account)

- now, I am trying to test in API Face Detect online :

https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236/console

All my keys return 401

Sorry for my bad english : but where I have false ?

With best regards

Francis

Comment: Use either one of the key only. You can refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123633/access-denied-due-to-invalid-subscription-key-face-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your non-Azure key you've obtained is for the westus region.  You therefore have two options:

- Use the [westus API endpoint](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236/console). This may have latency implications depending on where you are, and where your images are located.
- Create a Face API account based on an Azure subscription. When you do so, you will be able to obtain a westeurope API key.

Comment: Yes ! with westus API endpoint that work ! (not with westeurope API endpoint). Many thanks :good and quick answer ! Regards