# Microsoft Face API - Error 401, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have used the Subscription ID in my App and am getting following error at runtime.

```
Error Domain=POFaceServiceClient error - http response is not success : 
                {"error":{"code":"Unspecified","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."}}
                     Code=401 "(null)"
```

I taken the ID from the Keys after creating a new service. I even regenerated them. Every time I run the program, same error is thrown.

Hope you guys have a fix.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123633/access-denied-due-to-invalid-subscription-key-face-api ?

Comment: Yup! Been there, done that. Didn't work!

Comment: Is your API key for West US?  The github [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-iOS/blob/e67a1ff0fb0d0ccb2ff7f121c9831765c6814c45/Example/ProjectOxfordFace/MPOAppDelegate.h#L36) is hard-coded to westus.

Comment: No. Its not. I've gone with the southwest asia option.

Comment: And you changed `ProjectOxfordFaceEndpoint` to reflect this?  It should be `https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/`

Comment: Yes! Tried that. I am getting the following error :

`Error Domain=POFaceServiceClient error - http response is not success : { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" } Code=404 "(null)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix it finally. :)

Over creating the API KEY, just make sure that you supply for `westus` server and the endpoint should be:

`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0`

In my case, it works.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing back then! :)